# What is this pop-up that appears at the bottom of your iphone screen called?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am making an app, and I want want to use this feature:

---

[image]

---

the problem is that I do not know what the pop-up feature is called, exactly. I have tried asking on Yahoo Answers but there were no useful answers.

---

**Question:** Does anybody know what the pop-up that appears at the bottom of your iPhone screen called? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called an "Action Sheet". You can read more about how to implement it on the [Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Alerts.html) site.

[image]